# Problem with hidden QMainWindow: application crashes after QMessageBox is displayed

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmainwindow, qmessagebox

```
// main.cpp

#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow* window = new MainWindow();
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}

// mainwindow.cpp

#include <QTimer>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget());
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    this->hide();
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
    timer->setInterval(3*1000);
    timer->start();
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(showMessageBox()));
}

void MainWindow::showMessageBox()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Hello,", "world!", QMessageBox::Ok);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    std::cerr << "Destructor called" << std::endl;
}
```

I click the window - it hides and QMessageBox appears. I click "OK" - application terminates, and MainWindow's destructor isn't called. Why does application terminate? Maybe I've missed something? Qt 4.7.0, Linux.

... Oops! It looks like I found what I need.

```
a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

When I need it, I terminate app using a.exit(0). But I still don't understand what was wrong.

**Yeah! Looks like I understand what was wrong.** This is information about method

`QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed(bool)`:

This property holds whether the application implicitly quits when the last window is closed.
The default is true. If this property is true, the **applications quits** when the last **visible** primary **window** (i.e. window with no parent) with the Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is closed. By default this attribute is set for all widgets except for sub-windows. Refer to Qt::WindowType for a detailed list of Qt::Window objects.

After QMainWindow is hidden, there is no **visible** windows. When QMessageBox is closed, **application quits**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the following: When the dialog box is closed, the application thinks that there are no more windows open (`setQuitOnLastWindowClosed` refers to visible top-level windows), so it quits. The destructor of your window is not called because you never delete the object!

This should print out the message:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow* window = new MainWindow();
  window->show();
  int ret = app.exec();
  delete window;
  return ret;
}
```

Alternatively you can set the application as the window's parent

Comment: Unfortunately you can't set the application to be the MainWindow parent as the parent-child relations require that the parent is descended from QWidget; QApplication comes from QObject not QWidget.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think when QMessageBox has closed it is trying to return focus to his parent (Your MainWindow) witch is hidden. This operation fails, and system is throwing an exception.

Comment: Try this function:
`void MainWindow::showMessageBox()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Hello,", "world!", QMessageBox::Ok);
    this->show();
}`
with out set 
`a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
`
If it won't crush - it means that it couldn't return focus to MainWindow and thrown exception.

Comment: Pass to `QMessageBox::information(...)` `NULL` instead of `this`. MessageBox now has no parent, but application terminates.

Comment: I reimplemented `focusInEvent` - QMessageBox don't try to return focus.

Answer (score 2):

just try the following - put this:

```
...
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
...
```

to your:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
...
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
...
    MainWindow* window = new MainWindow();
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

this should help!

Comment: Greate! solved my issue, thanks!